# How to block "via" senders in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, spam-prevention

I have this annoying problem in Gmail. Spammers are by-passing the Gmail spam filters and are so clever that I am not able to create a manual filter of my own to block them. They are sending me junk mails from e-mail IDs of the form:

```
Jewelskart@greatestjewels.in via watchstore.cleanmail.in

Shoppingkart@shoppers.in via watchstore.cleanmail.in
```

In general,

```
something@somethingelse.in via watchstore.cleanmail.in
```

Now, I cant set a filter for each and every mail as they are from different IDs. The common part is the **via** address which is `watchstore.cleanmail.in`. But when I try creating a filter with `watchstore.cleanmail.in` in *From* field, Gmail doesn't list these emails. In short, the filter is not able to detect **via** addresses.

Report Spam/Unsubscribe options aren't working.

How can I get rid of these annoying spammers?

Comment: Are you sure you've `Report as Spam` by clicking the Gmail button *every* mail you got? This should work for further mails. Btw, **never unsubscribe** to spam, it will just confirm that your address is correct.

Comment: @JMax Thanks for the reply. Though not every mail, but I used to mark many such mails as Spam. And thanks for reminding me about the  unsubscribe trap!

Comment: I'm not sure if GMail has this kind of functionality.  It would be a good feature for them to add so perhaps [suggest it to Google](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=suggestions.cs).  As for the `Report as Spam` problem, my thoughts are that it will just block spam from the apparent domain, not the domain it was sent via.  Again, this may be a good feature to suggest.

Comment: This is a great solution.  I used it to mark spam emails from a certain domain (with a random prefix) as read so I don't see the unread indicator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason Gmail's built-in filters won't work in this situation is because they can't be applied to the "X-Forwarded-For" header. That header is where the "via" domain info is stored.

My solution was to use a Google Apps Script to check my inbox every few minutes and automatically filter out messages sent via a specific domain. It actually works really well. Since implementing the script, I haven't had to deal with this type of spam at all. You can read my full walkthrough here: http://www.geektron.com/2014/01/how-to-filter-gmail-using-email-headers-and-stop-via-spam/

Comment: +1,Excellent workaround!! But I couldn't find the "X-Forwarded-For" header. And other "headers-site names" are not in easily searchable formats. For example, "Return-Path: <campaign-value4shop-10213-2596-859268-pavan8085=gmail.com@mails.cratusservices.in>". The culprit domain "mails.cratus.." is embedded inside the header data. Can we use regular expressions to search for strings inside the headers?
As of now, I am directly searching for "mail.cratus.." which is good enough for me, but may lead to false positives in future.

Comment: `string.search()` can do regex searching! Now my code works fine! Thanks for your help. Your answer has made me take interest in Google app scripts :) Until Google themselves come up with a feature to block via addresses, I will mark your answer as correct :)

Comment: Glad it worked for you, Pavan! I recently started experimenting with Google App Scripts as well, and there are a lot of cool useful things you can do with it!

Comment: @PavanManjunath Can you post your own answer how you did this without X-forwarded-For entry? Badly need this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter "via" emails with this configuration:

```
Has the words    replyto:@domain-to-filter.com
```

Answer (score 1):

I have heard from a friend of mine that there is a Chrome extension that can block an email address or even the entire domain all in just one click. I haven't tried it yet but I hope this helps. Here is the link: [Block Sender](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/block-sender/bklnjbfcmglhiaoppcckdodanccbelcg)

Answer (score 0):

I made a similar script, it checks for "Received From:", you can add as many domains as necessary in the `domains` variable.

```
//without http:// etc, just domain-name.com or domainname.com ....
var domains = [
  'secureserver.net',
];

  //This is not the best solution, a better solution would be to add a filter like this for example => From: #domainname.com
  //and then this app would read your GMail filters and test whether it begins with # to apply the next function if so.. but I couldn't find a way to read GMail settings from here

function filterVia() {
  // get all threads in inbox
  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    Utilities.sleep(100);
    // get all messages in a given thread
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    // iterate over each message
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      // log message subject
      var content = messages[j].getRawContent();

      for (var k = 0; k < domains.length; k++) {
        //make domain name as regexp
        var re = new RegExp('\\.|\\-', 'gi');
        var b = domains[k].replace(re, '\\$&');
        var regex = new RegExp("Received\: from .*" + b,'gim');
        var does_match = regex.test(content);

        if(does_match){
          //MARK AS READ (maybe spares you an unnecessary notification)
          messages[j].markRead();
          //DELETE THE MESSAGE
          messages[j].moveToTrash();          
        }

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ends up here looking for a way to filter received emails by a label and save them to the label's folder instead of marking them as spam and trashing them, here's a script doing just that (Edited the one provided by @ChrisZ).

```
function filterByVia() {
  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 5);
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("yourlabel");
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages=threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      var message=messages[j];
      var body=message.getRawContent();
      if (body.indexOf("the domain after via") > -1) {
        label.addToThread(threads[i]);
      }
      Utilities.sleep(1000);
    }

   }
 }
```

Hope it helps someone some day

Answer (score 0):

It has taken some work, but the answer turns out to be rather simple:

- In each email there is a header that carries the website of the "via" sender.
- In the email, upper right, click the three vertical dots, and choose "show original" and it should pop up in a new tab. It's the coded version of the email with headers.
- Scroll down and search for the line that has: "dkim=pass header.i=@(website.com)"
- Copy this bit
- Then in the actual email (original window), click the three vertical dots again, and choose "filter messages like this"
- In the pop-up window, go to line "has the words" and there paste what you just copied.
- Also, remove anything from the "from" line.
- Click "create filter" at the bottom of the window.
- Check the box "delete it" and "create filter" again.

Ta-dah!
That does it.

Answer (score -3):

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en

http://mashable.com/2012/06/22/gmail-filters/

My suggestion is try creating filters.

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail on what needs to be done? Link-only answers aren't as helpful as giving a recap here of the required action. Also, if the links go down, there's still something helpful for future visitors.

Comment: Nah that doesnt work