# How can I distinguish if I have to filter emails via sender or mailinglist (provider)?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I have a similar problem to the person [with this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30334/how-to-block-via-senders-in-gmail).

The e-mails I receive aren't totally unwanted though, but legitimate newsletters.
They clutter my inbox though. And as the fella above I noticed that I have difficulties filtering some - but oddly enough not all! - emails coming from a mailing list provider such as AWeber or MadMini. The problem with these pesky mailing list providers is:

Gmail doesn't seem to recognize those as a mailing list in the sense of a collaborative mailing list as it is used by NGO's, political-, student-, mum- and nerd-groups, i.e. **usually I cannot filter them by using the "list:" filter** that is visible in the third example within my screenshot below:

[image: Example newsletter e-mail addresses and their mailing list providers]

Another thing I heard / noticed: Some of these e-mails run via the same mailing list provider, but even though the (individual) sender/marketer doesn't intend it to, the mailing list provider somehow seems to use a different "via" URL! As you can see in the screenshot e.g. in the last example / row. All those little numbers in front of the top-domain seem to regularly and randomly get changed, making it impossible to filter for the domain itself! Except if I would set a wild card for *.mailing-list-provider-A.com. Which is overkill though: What if I want to receive some content from companies that use "mailinglist provider A", but not some e-mails from others that use company A?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Gmail there's actually a **very easy workaround**:

> **STEP 1:**  Instead of your main Gmail address, use a Gmail ***alias*** when you subscribe to new e-newsletters. For example, if your main email is "bob@gmail.com", use something like
>   "bob+newsletters@gmail.com". (You can use pretty much anything between
>   the "+" and "@" characters. More info on Gmail's alias feature
>   [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/1-awesome-gmail-tip-you-dont-know-about-seriously/) and [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/divide-and-conquer-your-email-with-the-power-of-gmail-aliases/).) And for the newsletters that you currently subscribe to, simply update your email address in their system. (Look for a link at the bottom of their email titled something like "Update Mailing Preferences".)
>
> **STEP 2:**  Create a new ***label*** called "Newsletters" in Gmail.
>
> **STEP 3:**  Create a new ***filter*** for emails addressed to your alias (e.g. "bob+newsleters@gmail.com") that: A) applies the "Newsletters"
>   label, and B) skips the inbox.

So it's basically just a different way of using filters. Instead of trying to flag down and set up rules for hundreds of different *sender* addresses and/or subject lines, you only have to implement one simple rule -- for a single *recipient* address. You can also incorporate stars and certain Gmail labs (like *Multiple Inboxes*) for even more control.

I've been using this method for years and it really helps free up the inbox.

Comment: It doesn't always work this way though. For example, Meetup.com doesn't allow you to add extra tags to your email address.