# Can I set up a filter for emails sent via a specific server in gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, email

I use gmail, and its a fairly old account so its probably floating around the internet from more innocent days.

I've noticed a good chunk of spam I have that's *local* to me is sent via the same service. I presume they got it somewhere, and its *not* one of my +suffix emails. Rather than unsubscribing to each vendor, I'd like to completely block mails sent via this service

[image]

Here's an example of one, sent by an insurance company. The domain its sent by seems to belong to an email *marketing* company - and as such is of no interest to me. I don't want *any* mails sent via their servers. I don't want to block admin@sgassure.com specifically *or* @sgassure.com. I know how to do that. I want to block the *service* they are using.

Is there any way to filter out emails sent via sendersrv.com or any specific relaying domain in gmail?

Comment: This looks like a question that has been asked before. [is:question \[gmail-filters\] via -"via a filter"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+%5Bgmail-filters%5D+via+-%22via+a+filter%22) returns 28 questions. Check out https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/30334/311306 from 2012; it has a score of +22.